# App Inventor 2 - How do I switch my 'button' image after a certain amount of time

Tags: android, switching

I need help, I new to this and have been having trouble switching the image on a 'button' with another image after some time. I'm using AppInventor2 to do this

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please tell us your software environment, software version and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html):

```
long time = 5000; //in ms, if im not mistaken 1000 ms = 1 sec
new CountDownTimer(time, time) {

     public void onFinish() {
         mImageButton.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.my_image);
     }
  }.start();
```